# forms fields returning None

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have form, of which travel_date and max_amt fields returning none after submitting the form from template code for ref:

**forms.py**

```
class GetQuery(forms.Form):
    origin = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'text', 'id': 'org', 'name': 'origin', 'placeholder': 'origin code'}))
    destination = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'type': 'text', 'id': 'dst', 'name': 'destination', 'placeholder': 'destination code'}))
    travel_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'name': 'date'}))
    max_amt = forms.CharField(max_length=6, widget=forms.NumberInput(
        attrs={'type': 'number', 'id': 'amt', 'name': 'amount', 'placeholder': 'Enter Price Range'}))
```

**Views.py**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        origin, destination, date, amount = request.POST.get('origin'), request.POST.get('destination'), request.POST.get('date'), request.POST.get('amount')
        print(origin, destination, date, amount)
    IC = AC.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    form = GetQuery

    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'IC':IC, 'form': form})
```

**template**

```
<form name="TravelQuery" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                          {{ form.origin|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                          {{ form.destination|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                          {{ form.max_amt|as_crispy_field }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{ form.travel_date|as_crispy_field }}
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary primary-btn text-uppercase">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

getting values for origin and destination but not for travel_date and max_amt.

Comment: You use `request.POST.get('date')` iso `request.POST.get('travel_date')`

Comment: Thanks It's work, my question is didn't we have to give attribute name value in request.POST.get()?

Comment: no, Django will inject the name based on the name of the field, and this take precedence. Using attrs for type, etc. is not good practice, nor is using `request.POST.get...`, typically you use the form again with `GetQuery(request.POST)` to capture the data.

Answer (score 0):

Change post to POST in the html form and it can be be written cleanly like this

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GetQuery(request.POST or None):
        if form.is_valid():
            origin = form.cleaned_data['origin']
            destination = form.cleaned_data['destination']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            amount = form.cleaned_data['amount']    
        print(origin, destination, date, amount)
        IC = AC.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
        form = GetQuery
    
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'IC':IC, 'form': form})
```

instead of

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        origin, destination, date, amount = request.POST.get('origin'), request.POST.get('destination'), request.POST.get('date'), request.POST.get('amount')
        print(origin, destination, date, amount)
    IC = AC.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    form = GetQuery

    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'IC':IC, 'form': form})
```